# How to make non-utf8 encoding works for ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, encoding, utf-8

My model insertion is in Shift_jis (Japanese),

The file has `#encoding: shift_jis` at the begining, then I do,

```
User.create({ user_name: "管理者" })
```

The character is shift_jis encoded!

My database is oracle (using oracle_enhanced ruby gems), which is also shift_jis encoded.

My OS is Windows-10 English but with Japanese as primary language (but I think default encoding is unicode?).

However, during the insertion, there's an error of:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+7BA1 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from Shift_JIS to UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252
```

So here's the question:

1. I can probably understand that ActiveRecord internally converts shift_jis to utf-8, but how to let it insert into database as shift_jis?
2. Why there is a conversion to WINDOWS-1252?
3. Is there a solution for that? I tried to use utf-8 encoding for ActiveRecord (database is shift_jis which is strictly not changable), and I added `encoding: sjis` in database.yml, however, ActiveRecord still insert the data ase utf-8 without conversion. So the database returns error (character too long, it's understandable that utf-8 has longer bytes than shift_jis encoding).
4. Frankly I don't understand why ActiveRecord started to embrace utf-8 but dropped all supports for non-utf8 encoding. Database charset migration is too sensible for managers and they can't afford any such changes but it's hell for programmers to upgrade from rails legacy (where everything works) to latest version of rails (where such simple thing breaks and solution is hard to find).

---

As requested (I just changed my encoding to utf-8, but error is same, there's just not shift-jis to utf-8 conversion, but still error for utf-8 to windows-1252):

Path information removed because of 300000 characters limitation.

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+7BA1 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252: INSERT INTO "USERS" ("ID", "LOGIN", "HASHED_PASSWORD", "SALT", "USER_NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "MAIL", "MAIL_NOTIFICATION", "CREATED_AT", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7, :a8, :a9, :a10, :a11)
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:121:in `encode'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:121:in `create'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:504:in `make_bind_object'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:99:in `bind_param'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:143:in `bind_param'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `each_with_index'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `block in exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1353:in `log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:121:in `exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:108:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:524:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:75:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:133:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/db/migrate/20081113061046_load_users_data.rb:43:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
C:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1046:in `ddl_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+7BA1 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252: INSERT INTO "USERS" ("ID", "LOGIN", "HASHED_PASSWORD", "SALT", "USER_NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "MAIL", "MAIL_NOTIFICATION", "CREATED_AT", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7, :a8, :a9, :a10, :a11)
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:121:in `encode'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:121:in `create'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:504:in `make_bind_object'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:99:in `bind_param'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:143:in `bind_param'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `each_with_index'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `block in exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1353:in `log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:121:in `exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:108:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:524:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:75:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:133:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/db/migrate/20081113061046_load_users_data.rb:43:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
C:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1046:in `ddl_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+7BA1 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:121:in `encode'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/bindtype.rb:121:in `create'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:504:in `make_bind_object'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/oci8/cursor.rb:99:in `bind_param'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:143:in `bind_param'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `each_with_index'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:132:in `block in exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:1353:in `log'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_statements.rb:121:in `exec_insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:108:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `insert'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:524:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:139:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:75:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:133:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `block in _create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:504:in `create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/db/migrate/20081113061046_load_users_data.rb:43:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
C:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1046:in `ddl_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Can you add a backtrace?

Comment: What about database.yml? Also, you wrote "The file has `#encoding: shift_jis` at the begining," but which file are you referring to? And why is there a hash tag in front of the line? The hashtag makes it into a comment, so it won't be executed.

Comment: The #encoding is the source code .rb file, which tells ruby that this file is encoded as shift_jis, so when ruby reads japanese characters it can inteprete correctly. Btw, I have solved this problem, I will update the answer.

Comment: Ah great! Haha. I wrote 90% of a long investigation into the issue and then had to finish filing taxes before I could post. Similar conclusion as yours. I'll post anyway just to shed some more light into the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution that works is:

in boot.rb, add this line of code:

ENV['NLS_LANG'] ||= 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.JA16SJIS'

This will tell activerecord or oracle_enhanced gem to save in database as SJIS encoding.

---

However, I have to say that the ActiveRecord::Fixtures still doesn't work. Fixtures still tries to insert into database as utf-8.

Look at my another question that still doesn't have an answer yet.

[Fixtures: How to load utf-8 characters and convert to non utf-8 and save into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492113/fixtures-how-to-load-utf-8-characters-and-convert-to-non-utf-8-and-save-into-da)

---

Final edit: fixtures also solved.